# Editing the get_string function in Game Maker Studio 2

Tags: game-maker-studio-2, game-maker-language

Everything works yet when I get prompted up to enter my name it looks like an error. Is there anyway I can edit it?

I am new to GameMaker, this is just my personal work for fun.

I have been looking online for a solution but it does not seem to be anywhere, I not sure if it's possible.

The following is the code that I am referring to.

```
if (currentHealth <= 0) {
    name = get_string("Please enter your name: ","Anonymus");
    highscore_add(name, global.points);
    room_goto(GAMEOVER);
}
```

Comment: If you mean writing text, I think you'll need to program that function in. As far I know, there's no default function to write text, so you'll need to check keyboard input and write out the string letter by letter.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try "get_string_async()"
get_string should only be used for debugging. if you use get_string_async() your code will look like this

Create Event:

```
    async = -1
    input = 0
```

Step Event:

```
        if (currentHealth <= 0 && input == 0) {
        name = get_string_async("Please enter your name: ","Anonymus");
        input = 1
        }
```

Async_Dialogue Event:

```
   var i_d = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "id");
if i_d == async
   {
   if ds_map_find_value(async_load, "status")
      {
         name = ds_map_find_value(async_load, "result");
         highscore_add(name, global.points);
         room_goto(GAMEOVER);
      }
```

This works fine for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want an "input field" (term to look for), you can use `keyboard_string`. For example,

Create:

```
keyboard_string = "";
```

Step:

```
if (keyboard_check_pressed(vk_enter)) {
    input = keyboard_string;
    // ... do something with `input`
}
```

Draw:

```
draw_text(x, y, keyboard_string);
```

Or [a slightly less basic](https://yal.cc/gamemaker-input-field/) example that I made in 2013.